# Remove entry that matches "this text" from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Ok, I've searched, and searched and I've not been able to find a way to make this work. Here's what I have:

I'm working on a chat application in node/express/socketio, etc. I'm trying to create a 'clear' function to remove a certain chat message from MongoDB based on input specified. For example:

```js
/clear badword
/clear heck
/clear Barbara Streisand
```

I'm struggling to create a proper RegEx that will actually find entries that contain the specified text.

Here's what I'm using currently:

```
Chat.remove({"msg":{$regex: new RegExp('.*' + myInput, 'i')}});
```

It just doesn't seem to find anything. Note: The specified text can be anywhere in the chat message, so I need to be able to say:

If `<this text>` exists anywhere in the msg key, remove it.

I have been looking at RegEx documentation for hours now and I can't make any of it work. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried testing your regexs on a static text string rather than on the database (via your code), to be sure that you have constructed them correctly and they are working?

Comment: @JohnnyHK -- yes, I'm using mongoose

Comment: @Xotic750   I was able to do it succesfully from the mongo cli using   `db.messages.remove({"msg": /*sometext.*})`  -- but I get an  "invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor" error when I try to use that in my actual code. From what I understand I can only use, g,m,i for those -- but that doesn't work properly. That's why I'm stuck here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either provide a callback to your `remove` call, or call `exec` on the query object it returns to actually execute the remove operation.

So either:

```
Chat.remove({"msg":{$regex: new RegExp('.*' + myInput, 'i')}}, (err) => {...});
```

Or

```
Chat.remove({"msg":{$regex: new RegExp('.*' + myInput, 'i')}}).exec();
```

One note on your regex: you don't need to add the `'.*'` prefix.

Comment: Ok, well I feel silly now.. simply adding the .exec() to the end of it made it work. This is why I love stackoverflow! So many  knowledgeable people. Thank you very much!!!